# Can ViewModel has static methods?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-adapter, android-viewmodel

I have multiple Activities with the same CardView. To inflate this CardView I reuse the ViewHolder in my adapter. Now I'm trying to handle a click on the ViewHolder with `setOnClickListener()` and I need to save the Model represented by CardView into the database using a Repository. So for MVVM, the repository can communicate only with ViewModels and Databases or other resources, but every Activity has a different ViewModel so I couldn't pass the ViewModel to the Adapter to update the Model into the Database.

So I'm thinking that the adapter that I reuse, needs only one ViewModel for the database actions indifferently from the Activity that uses it.
So I need a static method in the main ViewModel that saves that Model.

This approach is correct for the MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly but I guess that you want to somehow send a data from recyclerview adapter to your database.

```
"so I couldn't pass the ViewModel to the Adapter to update the Model into the Database"
```

You should **never** pass any **viewModel** to the **adapter** class because you will tightly couple them together and they wouldn't be reusable anymore.

In your case you should send data from **adapter** class and receive it in **activity**. Then **activity** should call **viewModel** to update specific data and **viewModel** will then call **repository** which will access database and save data.

It sounds complicated but it is well organised and you can reuse all components in many activities/fragments because they are not depending on each other. **Adapter** sends events that are received by your **activity** but the **adapter** does not know (and shouldn't know) which activity will receive the data. If you would pass **viewModel** as a parameter to the adapter class then it couldn't be used in **activities** that have different **viewModel**.

P.S Try to not use **activity** for all your views, in Android we have a **Fragment** component which is very useful in that case.

Useful links

- fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments
- MVVM https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-mvvm-pattern-for-android-in-2021-98b155b37b54

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to pass a click listener from activity to the adapter. In this case, the adapter can save the model because the listener knows the ViewModel

Comment: Can you show me the code sample for this listener?